# Printing array result more than once?

Tags: java, arrays, delimiter

I need the println to display only the first result (input[0]) but it is displaying it once for each split. for example, If I split the string into 5 parts, it will print it once more?

input: "Chelsea : Arsenal : 2 : 1"

output: 
Chelsea

Chelsea

Chelsea

Chelsea

please enter match result:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


                for (int b=0; b < 5; b++){

                System.out.println("please enter match result:");
                String s = sc.nextLine();

                String input[] = s.split(":"); // parse strings in between the dash character
                for(String temp : input ) {
                    String hometeam = input[0];
                    String awayteam = input[1];
                    String homescore = input[2];
                    String awayscore = input[3];
                System.out.println(input[0]);

                /*for(int a=0; a<input.length; a++)//length is the property of array
                        System.out.println(input[a]);
                */
                }

        }
```

Comment: Well, your print is inside the loop. The loop ends at the `}`. If you try to use the "format" option in your IDE, you could see better which statements are within which loop.

Comment: Take loop out of the `for-each` loop to print the data and change `System.out.println(fruits[a])` with `System.out.println(fruits[0])`.

Comment: I'm new to Java, thankyou both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `System.out.println(fruits[0]);` from inside your for loop to outside your for loop like this -

```
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            for (int b=0; b < 5; b++) {

               System.out.println("please enter match result:");
               String s = sc.nextLine();

               String input[] = s.split(":"); // parse strings in between the dash character
               for(String temp : input ) {
                    String hometeam = input[0];
                    String awayteam = input[1];
                    String homescore = input[2];
                    String awayscore = input[3];
               } 
               System.out.println(input[0]);
            }
```

Comment: Wow -.- Thanks!!

Comment: Is there a way to take out the "[0]" so it just displays he whole input? 
if I take out the 0 it gives me:
[Ljava.lang.String;@55f96302

Comment: try this - __import java.util.Arrays;__ and __System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));__ and  also I would recommend you to read basics of java array .